# No reactivity between service and component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I take out the logic in the service separately from the component.
There is a property in the logic, on which the display of the element in the component depends

The property is declared like this:

```
function serviceAbonent () {
...
  const switchAdd = ref(false)
...
return { switchAdd }
}
```

In the component, I get this property like this:

```
const { stitchAdd }= serviceAbonent()
```

In this method, I call the service method, which changes the value of the property

```
function newItemAdd () {
  serviceAbonent().add(newItemBlack, 'Black', 'CreateDate')
}
```

service method:

```
async function add (newItem :any, list: string, defaultSort: string) {
switchAdd.value = false ...
```

The problem is that when the value changes, the value only changes in the service, but does not change in the component. Why is that ?

Comment: They are unrelated refs on each serviceAbonent() call. In case you expected it to behave like global state, you need create switchAdd  once.

Comment: ^^ in other words, put `const switchAdd = ref(false)` outside of `function serviceAbonent` (I think)

Comment: You are just wizards. Thank very much :)